# Google apps script for Spreadsheets: How to hide a helper function in Script manager?

Tags: spreadsheet, google-apps, google-apps-script

I have customised a menu in Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

The problem I have is that all the helper functions I am using are listed when I press Script Manager.

I would like to hide them, I have read that if I put an underscore at the end of the function name, but it didn't work.

From [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/es/googleapps/appsscript/guide_writing_scripts.html) they say that the underscore at the end makes that the function is only callable from another function and not the editor, but as you can see in the image, it is not working for me:
[image: imagen con funciones]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The underscore does nothing more than inhibit the function from showing in the Run from Script Editor dropdown.

> Running functions. Any function can be invoked directly from the Script Editor, except those with a name that ends with an underscore, which can only be called from other functions.

You cannot hide code in the script editor.

Comment: According [to this](http://googleappsscript.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/hiding-helper-functions.html) it should also hide them from the script manager, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: @UncleZeiv - You are correct. If helper functions showing up in the Script Manager is a problem I would suggest posting in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) with a [link to the blog post by Evin Levy](http://googleappsscript.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/hiding-helper-functions.html) provided by UncleZeiv.

Comment: Greetings from 2022. We still can't hide functions in the Script Editor dropdown.

Comment: Greetings from 2023, still hasn't been implemented!

Comment: Greetings from 2024, it's still early in the year but it seems like it still hasn't been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to wrap your functions in a class and then it's not discoverable as a callable function.

```
// Call it anything.
class HiddenMethods {}
```

And then where you define your function add it to this class.

```
HiddenMethods.doSomething = function (someParameter) {
  console.log(someParameter);
}
```

And to call it

```
function opOpen() {
  HiddenMethods.doSomething("hey");
}
```