# Best Practice to Store Keys in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to inquire for best practices in storing keys within the Google AppScript environment.

Currently, while I am prototyping, I just store the keys as local variables in the file where it is used. This key is used by all users of my App Script regardless of their domains.

Moving forward however I would like to safekeep this key in a more reliable storage. And would like to ask for advice on how to best safekeep these keys.

Currently, I am thinking of :

1. Using PropertiesService.getUserScriptProperties().setProperty(key,value) as this is shared by all users.
2. as part of the manifest? Is there a way to add userData in the contextual and homepage triggers?
3. Or just keep using local variables as the code is not visible to the users anyway?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you ask about the best way to store a static key that would be retrieved by anybody who runs your Apps Script project, being indifferent to its domain. I also assume that the script is being run as the owner (you) and that the final users shouldn't be able to read the key, please leave a comment if that isn't the case. With this situation you have the following approaches:

The straightmost approach would be to use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties). In this particular scenario the key should be accessible to anyone executing the script, therefore [`PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getscriptproperties) is the way to go (you can learn more about other scenarios [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#comparison_of_property_stores)).

As an alternative you could store the key in your own database and use the [JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc) to access it. This method is compatible with Google Cloud, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle databases. Here you can learn more about [reading from a database](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#read_from_the_database).

Another possible choice is the Drive API. You could take advantage of the [application data folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata) since it is intended to store any files that the user shouldn't directly interact with. For this option you would need to use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) on Apps Script.

Please be aware that an admin from your domain could access (or gain access) to the stored key. Also please check the [quota limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) to see if it fits your usage.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jacques-Guzel. I understand now. I think the ScriptProperties-mechanism is the best route for me. However, how do I set this key though? Do I just make a 'special' version of my appscript, that sets the key in the ScriptProperties? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I opted to go this route. I just need to populate the script property using a special script and then remove the actual key from my code. Here is a sample implementation of such initialization : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455753/how-to-store-global-values-correctly-using-properties-service-in-gas

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! To write keys into `ScriptProperties` you have to develop something similar to `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('MY_KEY', 'my_value');`. You can learn more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#saving_data). After running that line once, you could comment it out or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed, the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) provides several methods for storing key/value at the document's level, user's level or script level:

- [getDocumentProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getDocumentProperties())
- [getUserProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties())
- [getScriptProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties())

I'd recommend to store a property based on who needs access to it. If only the authenticated user should have access to a property (such as for example a setting relevant only to its accounts, like it's locale language), go with the *UserProperties*. Contrary, if the property is relevant to a document (Google Docs, Google Sheets, etc.) go with the *DocumentProperties*.

With this said, I wouldn't recommend using the ScriptProperties in general. The main reason being that quotas apply to the PropertiesService (see table below). This means that as your add-on gets more and more users, you will hit the quota limit quite rapidly.

| Service | Consumer accounts (e.g. @gmail.com) | Google Workspace accounts |
|--|--|--|
|Properties read/write |    50,000 / day |  500,000 / day |
*Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas*

Depending on your use case, you might also be tempted by alternatives to the PropertiesService:

- using local variables in your code - *as you mentionned*
- using the [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service?hl=en) - which store data for a limited period of time.
- making request to a distant server where you could query your own database.

We heavily rely on the latest at my company, thanks to the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=en) service. The main reason being that it allows us to pull a user profile from our database without making updates to the codebase.

Comment: Thanks @Frenchcooc. I am going to try the ScriptProperties mechanism first. If that proves complicated, then I might end up using local variables. I am a bit wary of using local variables though. Is this a safe practice in your opinion, knowing the appscript code is invisible to the end user.

Comment: If you go with local variables, remember to suffix your variable with an underscore. Like this: `var secretLocalVariable_ = "invisible"`. It makes sure your users won't be able to access the variable.

Comment: Thank you for this. But can you expound what you mean on 'won't be able to access the variable'? Is the underscore a special mechanism where I can view the variable in my code, but my users won't be able to 'display' it? thanks and sorry for having to ask these follow up questions.

Comment: It's an old trick that function name ending with an underscore can not be called from the frontend (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875128/google-apps-script-for-spreadsheets-how-to-hide-a-helper-function-in-script-man) for more details). I believe it's applicable to variable name as well, but you might need to give it a try to confirm that.

Comment: Thank you again @Frenchcooc. I tried it with functions and it hides it from the list of functions shown when 'Run Function' is opened. According to docs, it hides it from the Script Manager, but such feature is not available for GMail Addons. As per the URLFetchApp, this is what I actually need the key for. I use it as an 'authorizing' key for my server requests. In your implementation, do your URLFetch() calls use some key to authorize itself?

Comment: Thank you for all the help @Frenchcooc. I have decided to go the ScriptProperties route for my problem. I just need to populate the data first (using a special build) before I deploy. Something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455753/how-to-store-global-values-correctly-using-properties-service-in-gas